# Excel VBA Set Variable to Equal Values between Dates

Tags: variables, excel, vba

In Excel using VBA, I need to set a variable to equal a list of all the dates between a start and end date (similar to equaling a range containing multiple values). The catch is only the start and end date are in a range, non of the values in between.

In SQL Server I've used the Sys.Columns table to generate a list of dates between two dates that are not actually stored on that table. Is there a way to do something similar here without having each date between the start and end date written somewhere? I googled for a couple hours and didn't find anything on how to do this.

What I'm attempting to do is have a variable I can do a For Each loop on. So for each date I will check if it exists in another worksheet, if it does nothing will happen, if it does not it will be added.

I've tried:

```
Dim DatesInSettings As Date
DatesInSettings = StartDate To EndDate

For Each Date In DatesInSettings
'Insert commands here
Next DatesInSetting
```

But that clearly isn't the answer. Help?

Answer (score 4):

This searches `Sheet2` for dates between the start date and end dates on `Sheet1` - in cells A1 and B1:

```
Sub RunDates()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim i As Date

StartDate = Sheet1.Range("A1")
EndDate = Sheet1.Range("B1")
For i = StartDate To EndDate
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A1:A5"), i) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print i; "- date found"
    Else
        Debug.Print i; "- date not found"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant! I had no idea one could iterate over dates in this way. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

The following subroutine calls a dictionary that will store all the dates between two given endpoints. Then it uses a simple existence comparison to check if the dates on your list is inside the dictionary's items. If it's not, it's going to print them out as not in the list.

Modify accordingly to suit your needs. ;)

**CODE:**

```
Sub GetListOfDates()

    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Dim DictOfDates As Object, DateToCheck As Variant, ListOfDates As Variant
    Dim Iter As Long

    Set DictOfDates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    StartDate = "12/31/2013"
    EndDate = "01/15/2014"

    For Iter = StartDate + 1 To EndDate - 1
        With DictOfDates
            If Not .Exists(Iter) Then
                .Add Iter, Empty
            End If
        End With
    Next Iter

    '--Print them somewhere.
    'Range("A1").Resize(DictOfDates.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(DictOfDates.Keys)

    ListOfDates = Range("B1:B15").Value
    For Each DateToCheck In ListOfDates
        If Not DictOfDates.Exists(DateToCheck) Then
            Debug.Print Str(DateToCheck) + " is not in the list!" '--Or whatever action you want.
        End If
    Next DateToCheck

    Set DictOfDates = Nothing

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a vector.

I hope it helps

```
Sub Dates_Vector()

Public Dates() As Date

    ReDim Dates(End_Dat - Start_Date)
    For x = 0 To End_Dat - Start_Date
        Dates(x) = Dat_Ini + x
    Next x

    For Each Date In Dates
        'Insert commands here
    Next Date
End Sub
```